# How to write Eclipse plugin to hide logger statements

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a lot of logger statements in code which makes it difficult to read. How can I hide these statements?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just change the log level in the application's logger configuration file? I doubt you would find an Eclipse plugin as console output plain text and the plugin won't know how your logger formats that text.

Comment: I want to hide the logger statements in Code, not in output.

Comment: Then you would need to write your own editor to fold/hide those lines. That's not an easy task.  You can start with: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_get_started_with_creating_a_custom_text_editor%3F